# field from category not available via craft.categories

Tags: templating, categories, field

my categories have a custom field called `titleTag` for SEO as well as a number of other fields. When I render them at their URI (`/categories/cat1`) I can output those fields easily with `{{category.titleTag}}` etc. However on the main category page I also have a filter button that loads another URI via `jQuery.load()` to filter the items based on category. So in the filter template I have this to start.

```
{% set filter = craft.request.getParam('filter') %}
{% set category = craft.categories.slug(filter) %}
```

I then want to output (amongst other things) the custom field values of the found category like so `{{category.titleTag}}` but it comes out null (the category found I am testing with has the field filled out.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `category` variable is no object of type `craft\elements\Category` but an `ElementQuery` in order to fetch the category you need to use the `one()` function

```Twig
{% set category = craft.categories.slug(filter).one() %}  
{% if category != null %}
    {{ category.titleTag }}
{% endif %}
```

Your `{{category.titleTag}}` printed the search criteria. Imagine you would like to set other conditions in your query: how is Craft supposed to know when your query ends?